# как проверить целое ли число язык си

Tags: c

мне нужно что бы пользователь ввел три целых чисел а если числа не целые то программа закрывалась я пытался делать проверку вот пример только здесь я зделал одно число что бы было проще
забыл сказать нельзя использовать библеотеку `math.h`

```
int main()
{
   int num1 = 0;
   scanf("%d", &num1);
   if (num1 % 1 != 0){
       printf("eror");
   }
   printf("%d", num1);
}
```

только здесь оно округляет число сразу после ввода а это мне не нужно
дальше я поменял переменную на `double`
но компилятор стал ругать меня

```
int main()
{
    double num1;
    scanf("%lf", &num1);
    if (num1 % 1 !=0) {
        printf("eror");
    }
    printf("%lf", num1);
}
```

помогите решить эту проблему

Comment: Остаток от деления вещественного числа на 1 - это сильно :-). Сделайте проще: используйте приведение типа в условии  `(int) num1 != num1`. Кроме этого, Ваша программа напечатает число в любом случае, даже если оно не "целое". Но это уже другая история.

Comment: я сделал вот так  ((int)num1 % 1 != num1) и все работает спасибо!!! проверил еще так работает  (num1 % 1 != num1)

Comment: нееет! зачем `(int)num1 % 1`?! приведение типа уже делает целое число, зачем для целого числа бесполезное `%1`?.. Тем более, что итоговая проверка с таким условием будет неверной.

Comment: мантисса типа **double** имеет размер 52 бита. К типу **int** нельзя приводить. Только к **int64_t**.

Comment: не судите строго я только начал учить программирование :3 я просто скопировал и вставил в место старого условия и оно не работает( или я вас не правильно понял

Comment: я понял что не так точнее в visual studio не работает  а в vs code рабротает так должно быть?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdint.h>
# include <stdbool.h>

static inline bool isint ( double d ) {
    return d == (int64_t)d ;
}

int main(){
    printf("isint(3) = %d\n",isint(3));
    printf("isint(3.1) = %d\n",isint(3.1));
}
```

---

```
isint(3) = 1
isint(3.1) = 0
```

**дополнение**

Если нужна точность и важность пределов целочисленного типа, то нужен двойной контроль. Сначала считываем число, потом пишем в строку. Будет считать, что введённое выражение удовлетворяет условиям, если запись целочисленного числа в сторку совпадает с введённым выражением. *Не поддерживается запись с экспонентой `1e1`, с точкой `1.0` и положительное число со знаком плюс `+1`.*

```
char s[100] ;
scanf("%99s",s);
int i ;
sscanf(s,"%d",&i);
char s2[100] ;
sprintf(s2,"%d",i);
if (strcmp(s,s2)==0)
    printf("integer %d\n",i);
else 
    printf("is not integer %s\n",s);
```

---

```
integer 1234567890
is not integer 12345678901
```

Comment: нашел вот такой контр-пример `const char* x = "0.99999999999999999";
    double r = 0;
    sscanf(x, "%lf", &r);
    printf("isint(%lf) = %d\n", r, isint(r));` Да, выглядит наигранно, но это пользовательский ввод, никто не мешает.

Comment: Я могу конечно дописать функцию `sscanint`. Но это уже не школьная программа. В вопросе нет условий на пределы чисел. Длина, отрицательность. Истинность. Возможность использовать экспоненту. Нет условия про систему исчисления и т.д. @KoVadim

Comment: да,  я знаю. Но я думаю, что `int c = scanf("%d %d %d", x1,x2,x3); if (c != 3) { prinf("ups")` более чем достаточно. ну там ещё в do-while завернуть.

Comment: Все языки сейчас опускают глаза с предупреждением, что они используют тип `double`. И вы должны понять и простить. Никто сейчас не пишет `Mathematics` сами. @KoVadim

Comment: попытался понять, но не смог.

Comment: Ну хорошо, был как-то вопрос про вместимость типа `int` при вводе. Нарисую. @KoVadim

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что все вышеизложенные предложения больше похожи на гадание на кофейной гуще, а не на нормальное программирование :-)

А нормальный путь решения этой проблемы только один:

1. Вводим **строку** содержащую запись числа
2. Проверяем наличие в строке десятичной точки
3. Если точки нет - преобразуем в целое.
4. Если точка есть - преобразуем в *double*

В изложенном подходе соблюдается дисциплина работы с типами и нет тникаких неочевидных преобразований.

Comment: `1e-1` - десятичной точки нет, но это не совсем целое :-). В смысле, проверять надо будет больше, чем просто найти десятичный разделитель (который может быть и запятой).

Comment: @Vladimir - "десятичной точки нет, но это не совсем целое" - Да, здесь я погорячился. Надо более тщательно проверять и учесть возможность ошибочного ввода.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
В случае ввода вещественного числа: "ERROR" 
Без <math.h>  Всем добра! 
*/
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int num, num1, i, da;
    printf("Введите целое число:\n");
for(i=0; i<3; )
{
da=scanf(" %d.%d", &num,&num1);
   if(da==1)
      i++;
   else 
      break;
}
if(da==2) 
    printf("ERROR\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Решение есть, но какова его практическая ценность? Похоже что нулевая. При каких таких обстоятельствах может отсутствовать возможность подключить <math.h>? Вероятно существует какая-то возможность ехать на машине если у неё нет одного колеса, но зачем?